# Stereo vision: Coresponding coordinates

Tags: matlab, matching, stereo-3d, matlab-cvst

Please could you help me understand to the code from Matlab Help about Stereo vision - Basic Block Matching?

```
% Scan over all rows.
for m=1:nRowsLeft
    % Set min/max row bounds for image block.
    minr = max(1,m-halfBlockSize);
    maxr = min(nRowsLeft,m+halfBlockSize);
    % Scan over all columns.
    for n=1:size(leftI,2)
        minc = max(1,n-halfBlockSize);
        maxc = min(size(leftI,2),n+halfBlockSize);
        % Compute disparity bounds.
        mind = max( -disparityRange, 1-minc );
        maxd = min( disparityRange, size(leftI,2)-maxc );

        % Construct template and region of interest.
        template = rightI(minr:maxr,minc:maxc);
        templateCenter = floor((size(template)+1)/2);
        roi = [minc+templateCenter(2)+mind-1 ...
               minr+templateCenter(1)-1 ...
               maxd-mind+1 1];
        % Lookup proper TemplateMatcher object; create if empty.
        if isempty(tmats{size(template,1),size(template,2)})
            tmats{size(template,1),size(template,2)} = ...
                vision.TemplateMatcher('ROIInputPort',true);
        end
        thisTemplateMatcher = tmats{size(template,1),size(template,2)};

        % Run TemplateMatcher object.
        loc = step(thisTemplateMatcher, leftI, template, roi);
        Dbasic(m,n) = loc(1) - roi(1) + mind;
    end
    waitbar(m/nRowsLeft,hWaitBar);
end
```

According to Matlab help: **loc** contains location coordinates of the point in the left image and **roi** contains `[x y width height]` of the region in the right image where x and y are coordinates of the upper left corner.

I want to know corresponding coordinates in the left and right image. For the left image: `x = loc(1)`, `y = loc(2)` and for the right image: `x = roi(1) - mind, y = loc(2)`

Is this correct? I am not sure what exactly is inside roi.

Comment: If I remember well, `Dbasic` is a grid that contain the seed of the block matching for a specific iteration.

Comment: @AlexandreBizeau According to this step `Dbasic(m,n) = loc(1) - roi(1) + mind;` during every iteration, I assume `Dbasic` contains a disparity map. Based on this, `loc(1)` should contain column coordinate in the left image and `roi(1) - mind` column coordinate in the right image on the same row. But I am not sure. I used this to determine the distance between the object and the camera with stereo vision but results are not as accurate as I would like. So I am wondering if this part is correct.

Comment: I tried to use that function once. And same as you, Matlab SGBM result aren't that good. I use Opencv Matlab wrapper for this and works well for me. But is there an error or you just want to understand what they do in that function ?

Comment: Matlab provides functions `disparity()` and `vipstereo_blockmatch_combined()`, both of them return a disparity map. But I need obtain only corresponding coordinates from the left and the right image. For this purpose I have transformed their Block matching function and get the coordinates as follows: `xL = loc(1), yL = loc(2), xR = roi(1) - mind, yR = loc(2)` in every itaration. There is not an error but I am not sure if it is correct. And thank you for sharing of your experiences, it is very time saving. I would like to get the most accurate results so I will focus on OpenCV wrapper.

Comment: Okay, You don't really need the disparity, but the matching point between both image. Normally, with triangulation you can do it. You need both camera information (Focal, center), the disparity map to get your depth and you can do it with X_left, X_right and X_scene. You start on your left point, use the disparity map to get the 3D point and convert it into right camera. I don't know if it good for you or not.

Comment: @AlexandreBizeau Yes, it is a good idea. I should explain to you what exactly I am doing. I am using `Camera Calibration Toolbox for Matlab`. I have done a calibration and I have extrinsics and intrinsic parameters of stereo camera system. This toolbox also contains function `stereo_trinagulation()`. Input of this function are intrinsic parameters of the left and right camera, rotation and translation vector between cameras and two matrixes of coordinates in the left and right image. Output are 3D coordinates of a scene point.

Comment: I assume this scenario will be much more accurate than calculate a depth based on `z = (b*F) / (d*s)`, e.g. cameras are not 100% parallel. I need to get matching points of both images. I tried to determine coordinates in the right image from a knowledge of coordinates in the left image and the disparity map. But the results are worse than the previous try. I am wondering if is possible get the coordinates of matching points by another way.

Comment: Like your first try, You'll need to implement your own algorithm. Because there no OpenCV function that have this return. But you can just do correlation with SAD to search for your best pixel. If you have rectify your image with Jean-Yves Bouget toolbox, you're suppose to get epipolar line parallel. I don't have anything else in mind. But I'm using this toolbox too, it awesome :)

Comment: @Alexandre Bizeau Many thanks again. I would like to ask for a last question. If I have distance to the left camera and to the right camera. How can I calculate the final distance to the middle of both cameras?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. But `T`, the translation between the 2 camera is suppose to be a vector. Just get the length of that vector and you get distance between camera no ?

Comment: My question wasn't clear. Output of `stereo_trinagulation()` function are 3D coordinates of the points in the left camera reference frame and in the the right camera reference frame. Hence I have information about the distance from the left camera to the point and from the right camera to the point. And I would like to get the distance from the middle of cameras to the point. From `T` I have also the distance between cameras and another information is `Rotation vector:             om = [ -0.00310   0.06848  -0.00276 ] ± [ 0.00665   0.01107  0.00046 ]` but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: I read the help of `stereo_triangulation()`, as `xL` and `xR`, just pass the center pixel `(Height/2, Width/2)` or the `cc_new_left` depending which one you prefer and you'll obtain the 3D coordinate for the left, do same for right. And if it well calibrate, both 3D point must be the same. But only in theory, in practice you will get an error so just do a line between point and get the middle of this line and you have your 3D coordinate. After just take `z` information and you have the distance from your camera.

Comment: Great and `z` information (`XL(3)` or `XR(3)`) is in mm or pixels? And the distance is from the lens of camera to the object or from CCD chip of camera to the object? I didn't find this information in documentation.

Comment: Okay, normally your camera are now parallel, so `XL` or `XR` are what you need. It's not the distance of a vector but only `Z` translate. That mean `XL(3) = XR(3)` normally. And it from focal plane if I remember well.

Comment: I didn't understand what exactly  is `z` translate. For example, `XL =  [12.5201; 24.6141; 784.1483]` and I thought the value 784.1483 is the distance from camera to the point in space. According my results, the depth - `XL(3)` - is in correspondence with disparity map.

Comment: So your point is about 78.4 cm from the camera. Is it logic for your scene ? Disparity Map is suppose to be in pixel and the `XL` in mm.

Comment: Yes, it is pretty close to the true value but still not so close how I would like to :) Anyway, thank you for sharing your knowledge! Actually I don't know what is the best way how to close this topic with correct answer.

Comment: Post your own answer and Accept it in 24 hour. That will help other people that read your question. I can post an answer too, but I don't know what was helpful for you :)

Comment: OK, I will do that :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `disparity` function from the Computer Vision System Toolbox instead, which implements the block-matching algorithm.

If you just need the matching points, you should use local features: detect some interest points in both images, like corners or blobs, extract features descriptors from patches around those points, and then match up the descriptors. This is called finding correspondences, and the advantage of this method is that your images do not need to be rectified.

Here is an [example of finding correspondences to estimate an affine transformation between a pair of images](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/find-image-rotation-and-scale-using-automated-feature-matching.html).  Here is an [example of finding correspondences for stereo rectification](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/stereo-image-rectification.html).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I know about `disparity()` but the output is a disparity map and I need the matching points between both images. It is the step before calculating of disparity and is inside `disparity()`. Have you any recommendation how to get it by effective way?

Comment: Ok. And it is possible with this procedure, to obtain the coordinates of each pixel in the right and the left image? Please could you check my reply to Alexandre Bizeau above? There is a description what exactly I need.

Comment: Now I am confused. If you need the "dense" correspondences, i. e. for every pixel in the right image you want a corresponding pixel in the left image, then the output of disparity gives you that, because it tells you the shift in x for every pixel. If your images are rectified, then the rows are already in correspondence. Then for each pixel in the left image you can get the x-coordinate of the corresponding pixel in the right image by simply adding the corresponding disparity value.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I realized this simple solution after posting this question.